# Ble distance calculation using Time

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon, android-ble, android-ble-library

Is it possible to calculate distance between BLE-BLE or Beacon-BLE device using **Time(T)** taken on packet received on receiver device with measured power or RSSI value?

Is there any formula for that?

Comment: Are you asking about Time of Flight (ToF) distance estimation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a formula for estimating distance from time of flight measurements from [this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01995171/document&ved=2ahUKEwio24y2q4bqAhWAZzABHXNbDfIQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3ZedOFwJzsFrTfcDsQMAfw).

However, commercially available Bluetooth chipsets do not provide accurate timers capable of measuring time of flight.  Further, smartphones do not provide access to such time of flight data.  As a result, such a formula is if little practical value for most use cases.